# Django: raw SQL queries with a dynamic number of variables

Tags: mysql, django

Is it possible to construct raw SQL queries in Django so that they accept a dynamic number of arguments? So for example say that I have the following url structure in my app:

```
/books/category/history/
/books/category/history/1800s/
```

For the first query, I'm looking for all books with the keyword 'history', and for the second, I'm looking for all books with the keyword 'history' AND the keyword '1800s'.

I currently have two separate queries for each of these:

```
keyword1 = 'history'
SELECT appname_book.name AS name FROM appname_book WHERE keyword=%s,[keyword1]

keyword1 = 'history'
keyword2 = '1800s'
SELECT appname_book.name AS name FROM appname_book WHERE keyword=%s AND keyword=%s,[keyword1, keyword2]
```

Anyone know of a cleaner and more efficient way to do this?

I'm using Django 1.3 and MySQL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you use Django QuerySet, like this:

```
Book.objects.all().filter(keyword__in=['history','1800s']).values('name')
```

Another possible solution using RAW SQL, coud be:

```
keywords = []
SQL = 'SELECT appname_book.name AS name FROM appname_book WHERE 1=1 '
SQL += ' '.join(['AND keyword=%s' for _ in params])
```

Comment: thanks, that would be ideal, but for a lot of other reasons I have to write my own SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could do something like this to dynamically generate a [raw SQL query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)

```
sql = 'SELECT id FROM table WHERE 1 = 1'
params = []

if 'description' in args.keys():
    sql += ' AND description LIKE %s'
    params.append('%'+args['description']+'%')
if 'is_active' in args.keys():
    sql += ' AND is_active LIKE %s'
    params.append(args['is_active'])
```

... you can put as many "ifs" you want to construct the query

```
with connections['default'].cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

This way would still be completely safe against SQL Injections vulnerability